# WPF Destructor

Tags: wpf, destructor, xbap

Does anyone know the correct method for writing a destructor for an XBAP application?

Comment: Can you please explain further? As it stands, this question doesn't make much sense at all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XBAP applications are **managed** WPF applications that run in a browser and hence shouldn't support deterministic cleanup.. aka destruction. The [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx) is the answer for any cleanup that needs to be explicitly performed.

Or if just wanted to run some code just before shutdown... look at the [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx) class, which exposes life-time methods/events like OnExit/Exit.